# Kendo UI MVC Server Wrappers; Grid; DataSource; Model Definition - Missing Methods?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, kendo-ui, datasource

When defining a DataSource Model for a Kendo MVC Grid DataSource, I only have two methods to setup the model:

model.Field(p => p.ContractId).**Editable**(false);

model.Field(p => p.ContractId).**DefaultValue**(0);

Where are all the other methods?  I need to define the membertype as when I try and process the grid filters on the server side, (using Kendo.Mvc.FilterDescriptor)  The 'MemberType' is null.  Hopefully this is not another dead end with Server-Wrappers.  The client side equivalent DataSource allows me to define data types......(number,date,string....)

Thanks
-Sabu

Answer (score 1):

The type is extraced with reflection from your field

```
model.Field(p => p.ContractId)
```

I do not think it is the problem to your real issue.

Answer (score 0):

use an attribute on your prop

`[Editbale(false)]`

`string MyProp`